# Change webcam settings

Tags: webcam

I am using Skype and have noticed that the tint is kind of strange and the contrast is sort of off.  How do I change the settings for the MacBook Pro's built-in webcam?

Comment: Is it only in Skype that you have problems, or is there also a strange tint/contrast when using the webcam in other apps?

Answer (score 4):

According to this Apple [discussion forum post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2321880?start=0&tstart=0):

> As you know, software always controls your iSight. Most apps,
> including all Apple apps of which I am aware, **automatically make the
> iSight settings for you and do NOT allow you to manipulate them from
> within the application**.
>
> In my own case, I have found that merely adding more light to my work
> room has allowed the automatic settings to give me adequate iSight
> images.
>
> However, **if you want to take manual control, the iGlasses2 add-on
> lets you manipulate many of the features that iSight** (and many other
> compatible webcams) offer. **Note that iGlasses2 may not work with
> every applications that can work with your camera.**
>
> You can get iGlasses2 here: http://www.ecamm.com/mac/iglasses/

This [Apple KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2090) also offers some troubleshooting guidance:

> Important: **Follow these instructions in order. Test the camera
> between steps to see if the issue is resolved**.
>
> Built-in iSight cameras These steps are for iSight cameras that are
> built into a computer, such as the iMac G5 (iSight) or later, the
> MacBook, or MacBook Pro.
>
> 1. **See if the issue is application-specific.** Try another application (iSight works with applications like iChat, PhotoBooth,
>    and iMovie HD 6) to see if the iSight camera exhibits the same
>    behavior in all applications. If it only happens in one application,
>    try reinstalling that application.
> 2. **See if the issue is user-specific.** Test your iSight camera in another user account. If the issue only occurs in one user, the issue
>    would be isolated to user settings.
> 3. **Find out if the computer recognizes the iSight** Check System Profiler (in the Utilities folder, inside the Applications folder).
>    Under the USB header, check to see if the iSight camera is detected.
> 4. **Reset SMC or PMU** Reset your computer's SMC or PMU, and then check System Profiler again. (SMC reset instructions for [iMac G5
>    (iSight)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1767), [Intel-based iMacs](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964); PMU reset instructions for [MacBook and
>    MacBook Pro](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964).)
>
> If your built-in iSight camera is still not behaving correctly after
> trying all these steps, you may need to contact Apple or an
> Apple-Authorized Service Provider for service.

In short, you can try adding an app to offer access to the controls or do a bit of troubleshooting on you MBP to confirm if this issue occurs on other applications or for other users. Worst case, bring your MBP in for servicing.

**Note**: Fixed typo.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Webcam Settings](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/webcam-settings/id533696630?mt=12) for a quarter of the price. I don't know how they compare on feature set, but it's been useful to me over the years.

Comment: That webcam settings app no longer works with my MacBook Pro 2017 camera. It works with my MacBook Air