# How does iGlasses work?

Tags: macbook-pro, webcam

So I've been looking for a way to change settings on the iSight camera built into my Macbook Pro.  I know iGlasses exists (for those that don't know what it is: http://www.ecamm.com/mac/iglasses/).  I was wondering if anyone had any insight on how it exposes settings to change iSight settings?

Comment: There is a answer for you here http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/50878/46541

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change webcam settings](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50874/change-webcam-settings)